# Spring MongoDB: How to remove strings from array by regex?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have a collection named `person` with document like:

```
{
  _id: 123456,
  tags:["abc","abd","bcd"]
}
```

Now using Spring MongoTemplate I want to remove from `tags` where elements starts with `ab`, tried multiple ways but without luck.

For example, I tried but not working:

```
        Update update = new Update().pull("tags",query(new Criteria().regex("^ab")));
        Query query = query(where("_id").is(123456));
        mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, "person");
```

Comment: Can you add value of query?

Comment: @DmitryNazarenko added the query